# MySQL: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'phonemon.type.id' in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I try to execute code below on MySQL workbench,

```
SELECT P.username, type.title
FROM 
  player P,
  phonemon PH,
  species S1,
  type
WHERE (S1.type1 = type.id or S1.type2 = type.id)
  and P.id = PH.player 
  and PH.species = S1.id
GROUP BY P.id, type.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT S1.id) = (
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM species S2
  WHERE S2.type1 = type.id or S2.type2 = type.id
)
```

but error happens:

```
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'phonemon.type.id' in 'where clause'
```

While when I add type.id to the SELECT clause, the code can run correctly, which makes me confused.
[image]
Why does this happen? I want to know why my query fails, and I want to SELECT only P.username and type.title, without type.id.
Here is the structure of the schema: there are nine tables belong to **schema phonemon**, including **table type** and **table phonemon**
[image]

update: if I annotate the line `WHERE S2.type1 = type.id or S2.type2 = type.id` in the HAVING clause, the code will run without error. Maybe it means in the Subquery table type can not be found, but what's the reason of that?

Comment: Does `phonemon` have a field called `type`?

Comment: Might be a bug in MySQL or the workbench. You can try it with multiple kinds of database software on https://dbfiddle.uk/.

Comment: Try assigning alias on `type`.

Comment: `type` is a keyword - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-T - and must be quoted.